# $X \setminus point$ not path-connected implies $X$ simply connected

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, connectedness, fundamental-groups, path-connected

Per $X$ be a path-connected space. Does $X \setminus point$ not path-connected implies $X$ simply connected? Thinking about curves and lines seem to suggest the truth of the statement, but I think that one can "build" a topology ad hoc to find a counterexample.

Comment: The wedge of two circles is not simply connected.  Remove the wedge point, and the space is no longer connected.

Comment: The second formulation of this question was the most (in my opinion, the only) effective one in conveying the request of a space $X$ such that, for all $x\in X$, $X\setminus\{x\}$ is not path-connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are asking the following question: Let $X$ be a path-connected topological space such that for **every point** $x\in X$, $X-\{x\}$ is not path-connected. Is it true that $\pi_1(X)=\{1\}$?

This question has negative answer. Consider $X$ which is obtained from the circle $S^1$ by attaching to every $s\in S^1$ a copy of $[0,1)$, where we identify $0$ with $s$. (Formally speaking, to define this space you start with a space $Y$ which is the disjoint union of $S^1$ and 
$$\coprod_{s\in S^1} \{s\}\times [0,1)$$ Then introduce the equivalence relation  $s\sim \{s\}\times 0$ for each $s\in S^1$. Then $X$ is obtained by equipping $Y/\sim$ with the quotient topology.)

Now, I will leave it to you to check that every point $x\in X$ disconnects $X$ and that there exists a retraction $X\to S^1$. It follows that $X$ is not simply-connected.

Comment: +1 for the nice example! In noticing that your space $X$ deformation retracts to $S^1$ where the initial conditions no longer hold, could we place an extra condition on our space to make this question hold true? Something along the lines of "If $X$ is a space such that $Y-\{y\}$ is not connected for each $y\in Y$ where $Y$ is homotopically equivalent to $X$, then $\pi_1(X)=0$."

Comment: @SantanaAfton: I guess, the only meaningful question would be something like: Suppose that $X$ is such that for every $Y$ homotopy-equivalent to $X$, every point $y\in Y$ is a cut-point. Does it follow that $X$ is simply-connected? The trouble is that there are no nonempty spaces $X$ satisfying such assumption.